# Kendo DropdownlistGetSelectedValue

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId).Name("ParentCategoryId")
 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px;" }).DataTextField("Name").Value("ID")
 .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => 
  { read.Action("GetKategori", "Kategori"); }); }))
```

This is my code, but i can't get selected item value. how can i get ID from selected value?

Answer (score 0):

Register the select event of the dropdown by using `.events`

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId)
          .Name("ParentCategoryId")                 
          .DataTextField("Name")              
          .DataValueField("Id") 
          .Events("FunctionName")                     
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
               {
                   read.Action("Action", "Controller")
                      .Data("OnAdditionalData");
               })
                . ServerFiltering(true);
          })     
        )
```

Then in the script

```
 function FunctionName() {
var value = $("#ParentCategoryId").val();
 }
```

Comment: how can i set value with model.ParentCategoryId (model.ParentCategoryId = value)?

Comment: when do you want to set the value, the 1st selected value when the page renders will be the first item in the ddl

Comment: i need to get ID from selected value when slected item changed on dropdownlist.

Comment: if you copy and pasted it might be off, because the datatext/value fields are case sensitive.

Comment: Dursun, please remember to mark your own answer as the solution, and upvote/downvote answers if you find the content helpful/unhelpful. This helps other community members find the most relevant answers if they have problems similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed my problem. Problem is datavalue field, Sample Code id

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId).Name("ParentCategoryId").HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:300px;"}).DataTextField("Name").Value("ID").DataValueField("ID")
                          .DataSource(source => { source.Read(read => { read.Action("GetKategori", "Kategori"); }); }))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function FunctionName() {
    var value = $("#ParentCategoryId").data().kendoDropDownList.value();
}
```